# SwiftUI. Present a detail view pushed from the root view as the initial application view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I have two SwiftUI views, the first view has a navigation link to the second view and I want to show the second view that is "pushed" out of the first view, as the initial application view.

This is the behavior of the iOS Notes app, where users see a list of notes as the initial view controller and can return to the folder list with the back navigation button.

Can I implement this with SwiftUI and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own implementation based on [@Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030/asperi) and [@Mohammad Rahchamani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2810741/mohammad-rahchamani) answers.

This implementation allows you to navigate even from a list with multiple navigation links. Tested on Xcode 12 with SwiftUI 2.0.

```
struct IOSFolderListView: View {
@State var isActive = false
@State var wasViewShown = false

var body: some View {
    let list = List {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("SecondView").onAppear {
            self.wasViewShown = true
        }, isActive: $isActive) {
            Text("SecondView")
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("ThirdView")) {
            Text("ThirdView")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.isActive = false
        }
    }
    if wasViewShown {
        list.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("FirstView")
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Image(systemName: "folder.badge.plus"), trailing: Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil"))
    } else {
        list.opacity(0)
            .onAppear {
                self.isActive = true
            }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple demo. Prepared & tested with Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), isActive: $isActive) {
                Text("First View")
            }
        }
        .onAppear { self.isActive = true }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Your example works fine, but in my app I can still see the first view and its transition to the second because it's larger than just one NavigationLink. I see my first view for 0.15 seconds or something like that. Do you have any ideas about how I can fix it?

Comment: Try using `@State private var isActive = true`... that should present the detail / second view without the first view appearing. If you do this, you'll not need the `.onAppear` view modifier.

Answer (score 1):

you can add another state variable to hide the first view until the second view appears on the screen.

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    @State private var showView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View")
                            .onAppear {
                                self.showView = true
                            },
                           isActive: $isActive) {
                if self.showView {
                    Text("First View")
                } else {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments to another answer, by setting an initial state for a variable that controls the presentation of the second view to `true`, your `ContentView` presents this second view as the initial view.

I've tested this using the simulator and on device. This appears to solve your problem and does not present the transition from the first view to the second view to the user - app opens to the second view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isActive = true

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), isActive: $isActive) {
                Text("First View")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work properly with my code. With your code, I can't go back to the first view.